# is there any way we can introduce the wildcard character in creating release in azure

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, release

[image]

Instead of default I want to select the particular branch from release folder like release/*.
is that possible with Azure?

Comment: Please check for the answer if helpful to you. Then you can sign it as a correct one to benefit others who meet the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can specify wildcards for triggers in the branch specification either through yaml or classic pipelines.

e.g.

[image: release pipeline]